# Why are there so many different notations for limits and colimits?

Tags: category-theory, notation, limits-colimits

My question is relatively simple: Why are there so many different notations for limits and colimits? Is there a reason people don't just use a common convention? **Is there any benefit to using one notation over another?** Here are some that I've seen.

- $\text{Lim }F$
- $\text{Colim }F$
- $\varprojlim F$ (The most common I've seen to denote a limit)
- $\varinjlim F$ (The most common I've seen to denote a colimit)
- $\text{colim}_{\rightarrow} F$ (I usually see the arrow *under* the "colim," but I don't know how to configure that on here, edits are welcome).
- $\text{colim}_{\leftarrow} F$

This isn't all, as I've also seen things like $\text{lim}_{x \in S} F$ and even $\varprojlim_{x \in S} F$ (and in these cases, I wonder why the arrow is/isn't included if it's already clear from context what is happening). In each case, I understand what is being written, but I personally find it puzzling and slightly annoying that such widely different notation is used for these concepts. Now, I am at a point where I need to decide on a convention for denoting limits and colimits in notes, but I think that I should first understand why people use such different limit and colimit notation before I decide, out of the above six, on what convention I will use (as I would like to not have to later go back and change all my notation).

Comment: There are various notations for the derivative, but we’ve all managed to survive.  Pick your favorite and use that.

Comment: @Randall In other words, you don't know why people don't use a common convention, or what the benefits of one notation are over another. That's okay. Thanks!

Comment: The $\varprojlim$ and $\varinjlim$ notations are the oldest; originally limits and colimits were called "inverse limits" and "direct limits". However, the direction of the arrow is essentially arbitrary and not a good mnemonic. Therefore, many use "lim" and "colim", which is actually descriptive. I've not encountered "colim" with an arrow, but I would guess this is just a combination of both notations; though the direction of the arrow is then again in question (does "co" flip the direction of the arrow or not?).

Comment: Please read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985174/mnemonic-to-remembering-that-inverse-limits-are-limits-and-direct-limits-are-col/3987488#3987488.

Comment: My suggestion is to stick to $\mathrm{lim}$ and $\mathrm{colim}$, though occasionally it is ok to use $\varprojlim$ and $\varinjlim$ for their filtered versions.